# Programming in Common Lisp- calling the same list multiple times to a function as an argument

Tags: list, common-lisp

I just started programming in Lisp a few days ago and have been playing around with lists.

I have a function that can take one or multiple lists. If I want it to take 50 lists, I would have to type the list reference or the list 50x.

I created another function that does something like this:

```
(if (= n 1) 
  (setq combine (comboN '(0 0 1 2 4 6))))
(if (= n 2)
  (setq combine (comboN '(0 0 1 2 4 6) '(0 0 1 2 4 6))))
```

Would I have to do this for all N's? I tried using a loop from 1 to whatever number x, but have only been able to print x copies of the list this way.

Any advice would be appreciated. Not sure if I can do something like this with common lisp..

Comment: What exactly does `comboN` do?

Comment: Are you looking for the function [**make-list**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_lis.htm) that takes a length and an element and returns a list of length containing that element? You could do **(setq combine (apply 'comboN (make-list n :initial-element '(0 0 1 2 4 6))))**.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a function which takes a lot of homogeneous arguments, you should be using the [`&rest`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_dac.htm) [lambda-list keyword](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_da.htm):

```
(defun foo (&rest args)
   (print args))
(foo 1 2 3)
==> (1 2 3)
```

If you want to call this function with a lot of arguments and don't want to type them all, you can use [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm):

```
(apply #'foo (loop repeat 20 collect 1))
==> (1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1)
```

PS. Note that [CLISP](http://clisp.org) is just one implementation of the language ANSI Common Lisp.